# Webpack. Помогите понять, почему не запускается проект ( "Cannot GET /")

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

После того, как в терминале ввожу команду "npm start" то с виду, всё хорошо, ошибок нет

```
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8080/
```

а вот в браузере "Cannot GET /".
Не могу понять, что не так с конфигурацией и почему это сообщение в браузере?

Папка проекта выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

конфигурация файла "package.json"

```
{
  "name": "Drag_n_Drop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.6.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.8",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.16.8"
  }
}
```

конфигурация файла webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/app.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'app.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: 'dist'
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
            
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разобрался. Думаю, кому-то это да будет полезно. Нужно было дополнить конфиг вебпака и добавить такую запись в конфигурационный файл:

```
    devServer: {
        static: {
          directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        },
        compress: true,
        port: 8080,
      },
```